# Change SVG <circle> <rect> values through css

Tags: css, svg

I have this SVG code

```
<pattern id="thirdPattern" x="0" y="5" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <circle  r="10" cx="15" cy="10" />
          </pattern>
```

Can I change r, cx & cy values through CSS, Just like this

```
@keyframes move {
    25% {
        cx: 50%;
        cy: 50%;
        r: 60;
    }
}
```

or this

```
#thirdPattern {
            cx: 25;
            cy: 25;
            r: 50;
}
```

This code works, But the code editor does show errors becuase of `r` `cx` `cy` are not CSS properties.

Comment: There is also this *"Can I change r, cx & cy values through CSS, Just like this"* and the answer is NO for most browsers. That's not an opinion.

Comment: Ok...but the second one would still be opinion based and likely to get closed quickly as such.

Comment: I do not think that asking for the "Best Way" always opinion-based questions, Sometimes someone really wants to know what is the best way to do some stuff.

Comment: Best is subjective...my definition of "best" might be different from yours....thus opinions.

Comment: Where are you coming up with `<pattern`, `<circle>`, and `<rect>` as HTML5? They have nothing to do with HTML5. It's SVG!

Comment: @Rob It's SVG Then it must be HTML5.

Comment: @MuhammadJuma'a The SVG specification is entirely separate from HTML and in the XML namespace. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/ To claim it's HTML5 just because it can be used there is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html), but SVG 2 should support this. Browsers are gradually adding SVG 2 capabilities - your mileage may vary.

Comment: So, There's no way to animate SVG By changing the values like that?

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript or SMIL (use the fakeSMIL library for IE compatibility) - but, no, not CSS (at least cross-browser).